# "Inherited" data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design

I have a datamodel, which I want to describe in Rails. There are many `Entity`, each one `has_many :blobs`, and each `Blob` `belongs_to` one `Entity`. Additionally, each `Entity` may `belong_to` a parent `Entity`. It should inherit all of the parent's `Blobs`. Is there any nice way of modeling this in Rails? Stated differently, is there a way of doing something like this:

```
# Beware, wrong code
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blobs
  has_many :blobs, :through => :parent, :source => :blobs
end
```

Or maybe a different idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something very similar to this should work:

```
class Entity
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Entity', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Entity', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
  has_many :direct_blobs, :class_name => 'Blob'
  has_many :inherited_blobs, :class_name => 'Blob', :through => :parent, :source => :direct_blobs

  def blobs
    direct_blobs + inherited_blobs
  end
end
```